# cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const List<T>' to 'List<T> &'

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I implement a doubly linked list. Then I used that linked list as container for stack. but I get Error  C2662   'const T &List::last_elem(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const List' to 'List &'. I tried to return as a value but it didnt work. I dont understand whether compiler points wrong point.

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node() :data{ 0 } { next = nullptr; prev = nullptr; }
};
template<typename T>
class List
{
private:
    Node<T>* headNode;
    Node<T>* tailNode;
public:
    List()
    {
        headNode = new Node<T>;
        tailNode = new Node<T>;
        headNode->next = tailNode;
        tailNode->prev = headNode;
    }
    ~List()
    {
        Node<T>* current = headNode;
        while (current)
        {
            Node<T>* tempNode = current;
            current = current->next;
            delete tempNode; cout << "\nDeleting List!!!";
        }
    }
    bool empty()
    {
        return (headNode->next == tailNode);
    }
    const T &last_elem()
    {
        return tailNode->prev->data;
    } 
    const T &first_elem()
    {
        return headNode->next->data;
    }
    void remove_first()
    {
        Node<T>* tempNode = headNode;
        headNode = tempNode->next;
        delete tempNode; cout << "\nDeleting Node!!!";
        headNode->prev = nullptr;
    }
    void remove_last()
    {
        Node<T>* tempNode = tailNode;
        tailNode = tempNode->prev;
        delete tempNode; cout << "\nDeleting Node!!!";
        tailNode->next = nullptr;
    }
    void add_front(T d)
    {
        headNode->data = d;
        Node<T>* tempNode = new Node<T>;
        tempNode->next = headNode;
        headNode->prev = tempNode;
        headNode = tempNode;

    }
    void add_end(T d)
    {
        tailNode->data = d;
        Node<T>* tempNode = new Node<T>;
        tempNode->prev = tailNode;
        tailNode->next = tempNode;
        tailNode = tempNode;
    }
    void print_list()
    {
        Node<T>* current = headNode->next;
        while (current)
        {
            cout << current->data << "|-> ";
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    void reverse_print_list()
    {
        Node<T>* current = tailNode->prev;
        while (current)
        {
            cout << current->data << "|-> ";
            current = current->prev;
        }
    }
};
template<typename T>
class ListStack
{
private: 
    List<T> stacklist; 
    int index; 
public: 
    class StackException
    {
    private:
        string errMessage;
    public:
        StackException(string err) :errMessage(err) {}
        string getErrMessage() { return errMessage; }
    };
    ListStack():index { -1 }{}
    int size() const // number of items in the stack
    {
        return index + 1;
    }
    bool empty() const // is the stack empty? 
    {
        return (index == -1);
    }
     const T& top() const throw(StackException) // the top element 
    {
        if (empty())throw StackException(string("Stack is empty!!!"));
        return stacklist.last_elem();
    }
    void push(const T& e) // push element onto stack 
    {
        stacklist.add_end(e); 
        ++index;
    }
    void pop() throw(StackException) // pop the stack 
    {
        if (empty())throw StackException(string("Stack is empty!!!"));
        stacklist.remove_last();
        --index;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        ListStack<int> myls;
        myls.push(5);
        myls.push(8);
        myls.push(9);
        myls.push(12);
        myls.push(17);
        cout << myls.top() << endl;
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
        myls.pop();
    }
    catch (ListStack<int>::StackException se)
    {
        cout << se.getErrMessage();
    }


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The error is coming from `const T &top() const`, which is using `last_elem`. The problem is, in `top()` everything is `const` (because that's how you declared it), but `stacklist.last_elem()` attempts to invoke a non-const member function on a now-const member variable. It's not a bug in the compiler; its a bug in your code. Declaring `last_elem` (and probably `first_elem` if you want any consistency) as `const` will probably solve this: i.e. `const T &last_elem() const { ..code.. }`

Comment: it worked. thanks for your time. Normally I tried deleting const. i think i missed. thanks again

Comment: g++ also tells me that "dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11" for `throw(StackException)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make last_elem() a const qualified with:

```
const T &last_elem() const
//                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: @OlafDietsche yeah, you are right, I remember the term wrong.  Reworded answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is:

```
 const T& top() const throw(StackException)
```

remove the second const to

```
const T& top() throw(StackException)
```

And you should be fine.

(this is because the called `last_elem()` method is not const since constant methods can obviously not call non-constant methods, so making that one const would work too).